# Android: Calling method from thread

Tags: java, android, methods

I have a handler for a thread in my `MainActivity` that calls a method named `UpdateGUI`.

Both the handler/thread declaration and the method are within the `MainActivity`.

This is the handler Declaration:

```
Handler handlerData = new Handler();

private Runnable runnableCode2 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

     Log.d("Handlers","GET TOTAL RX BYTES:   "+Long.toString(res) );
        //Some code here that doesn't matter/
        UpdateGUI();
    }
        handlerData.postDelayed(runnableCode2, 1*6000);
    }
};
```

And `UpdateGUI` is as follows:

`public void UpdateGUI(){
        Log.d("Updater", "STARTING UPDATE");
//Code that doesn't matter here}
}`

From the logger I can see that `UpdateGUI()` is not being called from the thread. Can you explain why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Just to clarify. The thread is running,but for some reason it doesn't make the call to UpdateGUI().

Answer (score 0):

You need to atleast run handler once then only it will continuously called from the handler runnable method.

so call `handler.post(runnableCode2);` once in your code and that will be repeated

```
handlerData.postDelayed(runnableCode2, 1*6000);
```

hope this will resolved your issue.

Comment: The thread is running,it simply doesn't make the call to the method UpdateGUI().

Comment: ok sorry, i thought you didnt call that thread. now can you please put code that is written inside  UpdateGUI();

Answer (score 0):

I cant see you starting the `Runnable`.

```
Handler handlerData = new Handler();

private Runnable runnableCode2 = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

 Log.d("Handlers","GET TOTAL RX BYTES:   "+Long.toString(res) );
    //Some code here that doesn't matter/
    UpdateGUI();
}
    handlerData.postDelayed(runnableCode2, 1*6000);
}
};

// This part is missing
handlerData.postDelayed(runnableCode2, 1000);
```